# uWSGI max requests vs Flask (Python) Garbage Collection

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I am facing conceptual issue where I cannot find a valid explanation. I have a product where I am using Flask and uWSGI configuration. In uWSGI documentation, there is a parameter called

> max-requests

. The purpose of this flag is to respawn workers if the request count exceeds the limit specified for max-requests in INI file. The document says that it is used to prevent memory leak. The confusion is that Python-Flask have their own memory management and garbage collection implemented and it works significantly well. My confusion is if frameworks have their own memory management, why uWSGI is trying to do memory management to prevent data leak?

Second part of problem is that if the respawn happens, for that few milliseconds, the API which is already accepted by that worker takes few seconds to respond. It looks something like this.

```
Response Time: 32ms
API: /api/v1.0/ping 
Date: 2018-04-26 12:00:10

# respawn happens
Response Time: 7s
API: /api/v1.0/ping 
Date: 2018-04-26 12:00:20

Response Time: 10ms
API: /api/v1.0/ping 
Date: 2018-04-26 12:00:30
```

Is there a better way to handle this so that I do now respawn workers and rely completely on Python's garbage collector?

This may sound like a stupid questions but it extremely helpful if someone can explain me how and why of uWSGI? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Flask does not have any such thing. What makes you think it does?

Comment: It isn't a memory leak but rather a space leak. That is where the amount of memory used continues to grow as the program runs. A unbounded cache is a space leak.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman I meant Python memory management.

Comment: @Dan D. Then why would uWSGI mention in their documentation that this flag is used to handle memory leak? I’m totally confused.

Comment: That's splitting hairs. Unbounded cache is exactly the kind of thing that this is guarding against. Python won't do this itself.